# Naming Convention In Bitcoin Source Code

Tags: development, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-core

**Is there specific reference for naming conventions in Bitcoin Core source code?** 
I see regularity in class naming with prefix "C" (Chain, CInv etc.) or pointer naming with "p" (pprev, pnode etc. ) and am wondering if there's more to my list of prefixes or other conventions.

**Is there a Bitcoin-specific naming convention at all?**

Comment: I don't know if there's a formal reference, but the second thing you're describing is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: The bitcoin repo specifies their conventions here as well: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/developer-notes.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

- `C` stands for Class
- `p` for Pointer
- `f` for Flag (boolean)
- `n` for Number
- `sz` for zero terminated string

These conventions are no longer mandatory when contributing to bitcoin core.

You might also read https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/developer-notes.md

Answer (score 1):

The style guide for Bitcoin Core is available on [GitHub here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/developer-notes.md). It no longer details a naming convention, but as [Nick ODell](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/2306/nick-odell) already mentioned above, variables typically follow a form of [Apps Hungarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian) naming.

In the past, the style guide did include [a naming convention](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.9.5/doc/coding.md#coding), however it has since been removed because [it wasn't being consistently followed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4498#issuecomment-50391941).